# How do i create a list-posts-page?

Tags: loop, pages, templates, blog

I'm trying to create the actual "blog" page that lists all the posts. It seems like such a basic thing, but i can't find out how to do it.

Do i create a page and assign it a special template? If i do that, wouldn't the loop just grab the page content? I have a loop in a file called loop.php, which i want to use to display  the posts.

I tried doing something like this:

- Create a page
- Assign "blog" template to page
- From the blog template, run `get_posts();` which gets all posts.
- Right after that, run `setup_postdata()`
- Then just `require('loop.php');` to list all posts.

Unfortunately, that just grabs the first post; not what i want.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

A dummy solution would be to do something like:

```
    $posts = get_posts();

    foreach($posts as $post) {
        setup_postdata($posts);
        require('loop.php');
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
```

The only problem is adding pagination, which i will need.

Comment: There are about a dozen examples of exactly how to do this in the codex for [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts).

Comment: WordPress already handles this, under [Settings > Reading](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Reading_Screen) you can designate a page to display posts which will be queried in the default query/loop.

Comment: I've read it all. The problem is that the actual loop is in another file, `loop.php`. Look at my example above, that should work.

Comment: I'll look at that Milo!

Comment: So if you don't use `require('loop.php')` it works? (Also, you may want to use the [`get_template_part()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) function to include template files.)

Comment: @totels Actually when i wrote that example i thought it was working but apparently it just loops the first post over and over again. If i do `echo $post->post_title;` in the `foreach` it echo's the correct title. Weird.

Comment: @Milo I was hoping that'd work, but for some reason it just shows the content of the frontpage. I have no idea why!

Comment: Ahh god, the theme i'm using F¤U%&s things up, Milo's solution should work. Thanks!

Comment: Just to be clear on what you're doing: **1)** Are you using a static page as front page, and thus need to display the posts page on a separate static page? **2)** What are your settings for `front page` and `page for posts` in `Settings -> Reading`? **2)** What is the **filename** of the custom page template you're attempting to assign to the page you've assigned to `page for posts`?

Comment: I sorted it out, but it's really theme-specific so i don't know if it would help anyone else. It's also hard to explain. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're only trying to display your blog posts index on a page other than the front page (i.e. because you've assigned a static page as your site front page), you shouldn't need to do *anything* special. [Refer to the Codex for step-by-step instructions for creating a static front page and separate page for your blog posts index](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page#Creating_a_Static_Front_Page).

Some caveats:

- Initially, **don't create any custom page templates or other custom template files**. Ensure everything is working with the fallback template files (`page.php` and `index.php`, [as per the Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)).
- Note: if your current Theme includes a `front-page.php` template file, WordPress will use that specific template file to render the site front page.
- Note: if your current Theme includes a `home.php` template file, WordPress will use that specific template file to render the blog posts index.
- If you want to create a custom template file to render your blog posts index, use the **`home.php`** template file. Do **not** give this template file a `Template:` phpDoc header tag. You don't need to assign this template file to the static page assigned as `page for posts`. WordPress will use `home.php` automatically, if it exists.
- You should have no need whatsoever to create any custom queries or custom query loops, either via `get_posts()` or `WP_Query()`. WordPress will use the main query loop to render the blog posts index.